# App crashes if not linked to XCode or Instrument

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, instruments

I have a function that reads file and analyses it. It works properly if the device is attached to xCode or to Instrument, but it crashes when the app runs alone. Instrument shows no more than 1.5MB for allocated memory and no leaks.

After investigating I found that the function crashes after reading some records. I think it could be a memory warning issue.

The same function works perfectly if the app is linked to Instrument or if it's under debugging.

Comment: Check the crash log and the stack trace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485234/crashing-app-when-device-not-connected-to-xcode  that might help you

Comment: I found the reason, the reason was that the app is taking some time (for analyzing before it respond so the system kills the app), because of your help i noticed how to find the crash report and solved my problem, thanks a lot.
the solution was in performing the import task in background.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with your solution. Please don't put in comment, instead post it as an answer.

Comment: Because Of My Rank I Still Need 8 Hrs To Answer My Question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the importing function that it takes long time to perform which considered by the system as the app is not responding.

The crash report said:

```
....
Application Specific Information:
****.**** failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 10.050 (user 10.050, system 0.000), 100% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 6.495, 65% CPU 
....
```

The solution was in performing the function in background.

```
[vcImporter performSelectorInBackground:@selector(handleOpenURL:) withObject:url].
```